# spinner setOnItemSelectedListner trigger on create time of activity

Tags: android, spinner

when the activity has been created the spinner **setOnItemSelectedListner()** event is automatically call.
 how to **stop** this automatic calling.

Comment: You can't, but you can ignore that first event with a boolean flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    int count=0;
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        if(count >= 1){
        //do something
        }
        count++;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
});
```